# Swift fixing array for notifications

Tags: swift, notifications

I'm trying to fix my notifications displaying every day what should I pack up for school for next day.

Everything seems ok, but `content.subtitle` shows error :

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1007dbb00)

Is there problem with array also? I searched for answer, but it looks like nobody used array for notification body. Is it even possible?
And if it's not can I replace it with better replacement?
Thanks for any help.

```
let plan = [
    ["dzien": "Sunday", "lekcje": nil],
    ["dzien": "Saturday", "lekcje":["pon1","pon2","pon3"]],
    ["dzien": "Tuesday", "lekcje":["wt1","wt2","wt3"]],
    ["dzien": "Wednesday", "lekcje":["sr1","sr2","sr3"]],
    ["dzien": "Thursday", "lekcje":["cz1","cz2","cz3"]],
    ["dzien": "Friday", "lekcje":["pt1","pt2","pt3"]],
    ["dzien": "Saturday", "lekcje": nil],
]

func getDayOfWeek() -> Int {
    let myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let weekDay = myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: Date())
    return weekDay - 1
}

    @objc func registerLocal() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("Sukces")
        } else {
            print("Nie dzieła")
        }
    }
}

    @objc func scheduleLocal() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        let d = getDayOfWeek()%6
        let dzis = plan[d]
        if dzis["lekcje"] != nil {

        content.title = "Pack up"
        content.subtitle = dzis["dzien"]
        var lekcje = ""
        for lekcja in dzis["lekcje"] {
            lekcje+="\(lekcja)\n"
        }
        content.body = lekcje
        content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
        } else {

        content.title = "Tommorow \(dzis["dzien"]), You don't have any subjects."
        }

        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 16
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)

            }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1007dbb00)

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and check the exact error message.

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'Any??' to type 'String'

Type 'Any??' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: When posting questions here on SO in the future, please try to use English variable names. Understanding someones code without understanding the variable names makes it harder for most people to answer your question and hence it makes harder for you to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler infers the type of `plans` as `[String:Any]` and when you are trying to do `content.subtitle = dzis["dzien"]`, `dzis["dzien"]` is of type `Any` and not `String`.

You have to cast it to `String` in order to work.

```
guard let subtitle = dzis["dzien"] as? String else {return}
content.subtitle = subtitle
```